# Nextjs 14 response cookies won't return to the client

Tags: authentication, next.js, cookies, jwt, pocketbase

I am currently working on one of my project which is mainly focused on Nextjs api router (I've mainly used node with express in the past)
I'm trying to auth a user using pocketbase as my custom database.
I'm doing user auth using email and password and then storing the user data in a session as following:

```
import { encrypt } from "@/lib/actions";
import { db } from "@/pocketbase";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { serialize } from 'cookie'

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    try {
        const values = await request.json();
        const { record } = await db.collection("users").authWithPassword(values.email, values.password);
        const expires = new Date(Date.now() + 30 * 1000 * 60 * 24);
        /* the encrypt function mainly just to sign a JWT contract */
        const session = await encrypt({ record, expires });
        const response = NextResponse.json({ session }, {
            status: 200, headers: {
                'Set-Cookie': serialize('session', session, { expires })
            }
        });
        return response;
    } catch (err: any) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: err.message }, { status: 400 })
    }
}
```

My problem is that the cookie won't be sent back to the client at all and whenever I'm trying any diffrent approuch of sending the cookie it also won't work

Its been a few hours already and I'm frustrated by this

For more context: I'm trying to then access the session by this getSession helper function:

```
export async function getSession() {
    const session = cookies().get('session')?.value;
    if (!session) return null;
    return await decrypt(session);
}
```

And then I'm trying to access it in an AuthProtected Component:

```
import { getSession } from "@/lib/actions";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export default async function AuthProtected({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const session = await getSession();
    console.log(session);
    return <>{children}</>
}
```

I'm getting `null` in the server console

I appriciate any solution or if I've made some kind of mistake I will be gald to take any sort of reviews for my code :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I solved it and forgot to update
Personally my problem was that I was sending the request via server action and not from the client itself

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `NextResponse`, use `Response`

[From Here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-response-next-in-app-route-handler)

> Route Handlers in the Next.js App Router do not support using the
> NextResponse.next() method to forward to the next Middleware.
>
> The Route Handler is considered the end of the middleware "chain".
> Handlers must always return a Response object instead.